# I need to display the meta data on a document library in SharePoint 2007 to users that may not have rights to it.

Tags: sharepoint, ssrs-2008

I need to display the content on a document library in SharePoint 2007  to users that may not have rights to it.
The idea is that users can see the metadata but not view the document unless they have rights to do so.
I was thinking of writing a recursive ssrs report to display the list of documents with links and let SharePoint control the access.  However there are  conflicting arguments about the positive and negative effect on SharePoint performance and it would be a complicated sql recursive query to show documents in sub-folders.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to do this?